# Find the fundamental matrix of $x''-7x'+10x=0$ and determine if the solution is stable.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to find the fundamental matrix of $x''-7x'+10x=0$ and determine if the solution is stable.

$x''-7x'+10x=0$ can be transformed into $x'= y$ and $y'= 7y-10x$, solving this system I got that $x=c_1e^{5t}+c_2e^{2t}$ and $y=c_15e^{5t}+c_22e^{2t}$.

Would the fundamental matrix be:

$$x(t)=\begin{pmatrix} e^{5t} & e^{2t} \\ 5e^{5t} & 2e^{2t} \end{pmatrix}?$$

About stability I am not so sure, would it suffice to examine the limit $\lim_{t \to \infty} X(t)$?

Comment: The eigenvalues are strictly positive so it is not stable.

Comment: Ah okey, thanks